# Generate JFrames in a loop, naming issue

Tags: java, loops, jpanel

Beginner Java programmer here. I'm trying to create a card game to learn more about Java. I have an array of names I pulled out a database. For each String in the array I want to create a JPanel and inside JLabels where I will set the name, power, health, etc.

The problem is when I create these in a loop they all have the same name and overwrite each other. Since I read Java doesn't have dynamic Variable names, how do I solve this?

```
public void loadDatabaseCardElements(ArrayList cards) {
    ArrayList<String> buildCards = cards;

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i != buildCards.size();) {
        String var = buildCards.get(0);

        //create the Panel etc
        JPanel mainHolder = new JPanel();
        mainHolder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainHolder, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        JLabel name = new JLabel("Name: " + var);
        JLabel powerLabel = new JLabel("Power: ");
        JLabel healthLabel = new JLabel("Health: ");
        JLabel armorLabel = new JLabel("Armor: ");
        JLabel type1Label = new JLabel("Type1");
        JLabel type2Label = new JLabel("Type2: ");
        JLabel ability1Label = new JLabel("Ability1: ");
        JLabel ability2Label = new JLabel("Ability2: ");
        JLabel ability3Label = new JLabel("Ability3: ");

        JButton card1 = new JButton("Add to deck");


        mainHolder.add(name);
        mainHolder.add(powerLabel);
        mainHolder.add(healthLabel);
        mainHolder.add(armorLabel);
        mainHolder.add(type1Label);
        mainHolder.add(type2Label);
        mainHolder.add(ability1Label);
        mainHolder.add(ability2Label);
        mainHolder.add(ability3Label);
        mainHolder.add(card1);

        mainHolder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        mainHolder.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 130, 200 ) );

        frame1.add(mainHolder, BorderLayout.WEST);

        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame1);

        card1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                preDeck.add(var); //add to another array when clicked
            }
        });


        if (buildCards.size() != 0) {
            buildCards.remove(0);
        } else {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem in this case is that you add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame` in such a way it will override the current contents of the `BorderLayout.WEST` area.  Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html for information on layout managers. I would say, that learning Java through GUI development is probably not the best way. Fundamental concepts can be learnt through developing the model of the problem itself. This can then be tested with or without user input, then you can try and build a view as confidence increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for overwriting all the panels with same name is due to this part of your code:

```
int i;
    for(i = 0; i != buildCards.size();) {
        String var = buildCards.get(0);
```

You are assigning the first element of your list to each `JLabel`. This could help you achieve what you need:

```
for(int i = 0; i < buildCards.size(); i++){
       String var = buildCards.get(i);
       // Followed by your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set a growable layout for a standard jpanel in the frame and then add a new jpanel to the standard jpanel every time. this should solve the naming problem. if u need access to each panel, you can store them in an array